# Converting a word macro to vbscript

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I am trying to create a docx file with a different first page and insert an image in the footer

```
Dim oWord 
Dim oDoc

Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set oDoc = CreateObject("Word.Document")

oWord.Visible = False
Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add

With oWord.ActiveDocument.PageSetup
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
End With

With oWord.ActiveDocument
    .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter
    .Application.Templates( _
    "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\15\Built-In Building Blocks.dotx" _
        ).BuildingBlockEntries(" Blank").Insert Where=Selection.Range,     RichText _
    =True
.Selection.Fields.Add Selection.Range, wdFieldEmpty,  _
    "INCLUDEPICTURE  ""http://url.me"" \d ", PreserveFormatting=True
oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs("test.docx");
```

This errors out to

Line:   16
Char:   5
Error:  The requested member of the collection does not exist.
Code:   800A1735
Source:     Microsoft Word

Any clue to why this is happening?

Comment: Does the referred building block file exist and does it contain an entry named " Blank"?

Comment: Yes, This code was translated from a macro from Word 2013.
If needed ill edit the post to include the macro.

Comment: Try to call `.Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks` immediately before line 16.

Comment: Same error.
Is it a bug with word 2013? I will try another Install.

Comment: I just ran a modified version of your script (removed constants, replaced path with my personal building block path, changed building block entry name) and it worked perfectly. You're getting that error either because the `Application.Templates` collection does not contain what you specified or the `BuildingBlockEntries` collection does not contain an entry named " Blank". Try to split the code to see which it is.

Comment: Can you share the code?
Im erroring out on 
    .Application.Templates( "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\15\Built-In Building Blocks.dotx" )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is failing to open the building block collection specified. Here's an optimized version of your code that gets the path to the "Built-In Building Blocks.dotx" template dynamically.

```
Dim oWord 
Dim oDoc

Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWord.Visible = False

Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add

With oWord.ActiveDocument.PageSetup
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
End With

'Get building block path.
Dim bbPath, entryName, savePath
bbPath = GetBuildingBlockPath(oWord, "Built-In Building Blocks.dotx")
entryName = " Blank"
savePath = "test.docx"

With oWord.ActiveDocument
    .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 10
    oWord.Templates(bbPath).BuildingBlockEntries(entryName).Insert oWord.Selection.Range, True   
    oWord.Selection.Fields.Add oWord.Selection.Range, -1, "INCLUDEPICTURE  ""http://url.me"" \d ", PreserveFormatting=True
    .SaveAs(savePath)
End With

Function GetBuildingBlockPath(app, bbName)
    app.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks

    For Each t In app.Templates
        If LCase(t.Name) = LCase(bbName) Then
            GetBuildingBlockPath = t.FullName
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: This works perfectly,
But the document produced has the image in the body instead of the footer.

Comment: Thanks, I have accepted the answer.
Any clue how to resize the inserted image?